# Find variance within one pass

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Given a list of real numbers. Is it possible to find the variance with no more than 1 iteration with constant space complexity?

Comment: What is "one iteration"? In any case, you can count the numbers, add them up and add up their squares in one sweep, and from that compute the variance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: In particular, there seems to be a [quite elaborate Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) on this exact topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  If you know the count of the number of values, the sum of the values, and the sum of the squares of the values, you can derive the variance.  In particular,

$$\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2.$$

You can calculate the first term from the sum of the squares of the values, and you can calculate the second term from the sum of the values.

However, beware the caveats mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Formulae_for_the_variance